# button onclick event dont work in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

i have problem with my code. i have created button "sign up", i want when i click on that button a dialog called "dialog_signup appear.

The problem is it doesnt appear. and i always get this error so far

```
    **2>A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(_DeviceSdkVersion)" that evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition "$(_DeviceSdkVersion) >= 21".
    2>Build FAILED.
    2>

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========**
```

Here is my code

### MainActivity.cs

```
    using System;
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Content.Res;

    namespace GameLandPlus
    {
        [Activity(Label = "GameLandPlus", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
        public class MainActivity : Activity
        {
            private Button mbtnSignup;

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);


                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

                mbtnSignup = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnsignup);
                mbtnSignup.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
                {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    dialog_signup signupDialog = new dialog_signup();
                    signupDialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");

                };

            }





        }
    }
```

-->

```
main.axml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/images"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Create Account"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/createaccount"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/signin"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@drawable/butto1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5" />
        <TextView
            android:text="or"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/or"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:id="@+id/btnsignup"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@drawable/butto1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:shadowColor="#00ffffff"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/goodmess" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="35"
            android:minHeight="15px"
            android:minWidth="15px">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:background="@drawable/progressbar"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

-->

the dialog page i want to pop up when i click on the button

### dialogSignup.axml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#F1F3F4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp">
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/Firstname"
        android:background="@drawable/editstyle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@+id/Firstname"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/textEmail"
        android:background="@drawable/editstyle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Email/Phone Number"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@+id/textEmail"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:background="@drawable/editstyle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnDialogEmail"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/butto1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:shadowColor="#00ffffff"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/goodmess" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

-->

### and the dialog_signup.cs

```
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace GameLandPlus
{
    class dialog_signup:DialogFragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, saveInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialogSignup, container, false);
            return view;
        }
        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);//set title
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation;
        }
    }
}
```

-->
i do not include the slideup/slideright/butto1 because is the drawable file.
Please can u check on it.
I already change emulator so far. but i dont know where is the problem.
Any suggestion?